# voice independence in SATB setting

Tags: satb, choral

I am looking for a suggestion for sheet music.  I would like to study a piece of chorale or SATB style music that

1. is simple to read (preferably transposed to C major)
2. exemplifies good technique in terms of independent voices (simultaneous melody lines).

I understand the various types of movement (oblique, parallel, similar, and contrary) as well as the importance of melodic leaps in theory.  I would just like to see a pro use it in action.

I have an account on musicnotes.com, though I am only seeing Queen covers and Disney songs :/

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Note:  I have here a C major Prelude from WTC 1 (Bach), but the harmonic rhythm and complexity is proving too difficult for me.

Thanks!

Comment: If Bach is too complex, try looking at resources that attempt to teach the reader Common Practice Era harmony. Those resources usually have plenty lof examples. But unfortunately, Music SE doesn't do recommendations questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical choice for music theory students is the collection of chorale settings from Bach's cantatas.  They are published separately (i.e. apart from the cantatas they were originally part of) as a collection by various publishers precisely for the purpose of study.

Answer (score 0):

Tons of material at imslp.org and also books.google.com. Search for psalms or hymns. Ex. *[Chorale Book for England](https://books.google.com/books/download/The_Chorale_Book_for_England.pdf?id=PEcNAAAAYAAJ&output=pdf&sig=ACfU3U3s-HEZB29n6E01GMyPDcf6KFcqhQ)*.

As Alexander Woo suggested Bach's *[371 Harmonized Chorales](https://imslp.org/wiki/371_Vierstimmige_Choralges%C3%A4nge_(Bach%2C_Johann_Sebastian))* is a great resource, but it's harder to play than most hymnals.

Most of these things are public domain and can be downloaded for free.

*Chorale Book for England* seem ideal for you because of the simple rhythmic style. You can find similar stuff in *Reformation* style hymnals.

- [Havergal's](https://books.google.com/books?id=I7aIDHFgOrYC&pg=PT4&dq=havergals&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&ppis=_e&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_1OaQ5b3nAhXumHIEHX-GAw4Q6AEwAXoECAUQAg)
- [Maurice, Choral Harmony](https://books.google.com/books?id=qtPdEi0g6RIC&pg=PA5&dq=collection%20of%20tunes%20in%20short%20score&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&ppis=_e&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiL_bnf5r3nAhX0knIEHXoNDmgQ6AEwAXoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=collection%20of%20tunes%20in%20short%20score&f=false)